# is there a way to integrate an IDE with rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ide

I wanted to provide an online terminal or an online IDE to my rails app.

Is there a way to integrate any of the present IDE's to integrate with rails or to create a new one? I cannot find anything related to this on Google.

It is very much possible as there are sites using online IDE's like codecademy, codelearn etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check https://koding.com/Home . It gives you the necessary environment to start developing your apps, run them, collaborate.